Cordova app white screen and loading loop
I migrated my app made with Cordova to Android 13. But when I open the app, I only get a white screen, and with Inspect with Chrome I see that it is refreshing infinitely, see the video
https://streamable.com/y0i68d
Can anyone help me with this?
I already tried removing the splash screen and it didn't work
